# I have issue in adding new event in to the Google calendar

Tags: vba, google-calendar-api

I can check the calendar response and can see the events in it by GET method, but when i try to create new event with POST method then i have issue 405 not allowed
this is a part of the VBA code in Excel this part does not work
URL is partially, i am using ical method

```vb
Set Http = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
URL = "https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/......................."
Method = "POST"
With Http
Call .Open("POST", URL, False)
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    .send (Body)
    MsgBox .Status & " - " & .statusText  
End With
```

Comment: Could you please format your question better? Use punctuation please. Format what is returned, the URL more clearly. I am having trouble understanding what you are asking.

Comment: What is in the Body? Also, are you sure your calendar allows the method post? You receive 405 which is clearly a server side error telling that Post is not allowed.

Comment: Is it Calendar API you are trying to use? Is it [Events: insert](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) that you're trying to call? Did you go through the OAuth workflow? What body are providing, and what's the complete format of the URL you're accessing?

Comment: Ok i have to set events on Google calendar with Excels VBA code, i am using the "ical" method (authentication is not needed for "ical"). I send the "GET" command and got the response from server "200-ok" and gote status text. I have issue when i try to set event on calendar, i did OAuth and got the user ID and secret codes and put them in the code, but i am steel having some issue, for any case here is the link of my file, i am using my  test account and calendar [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/163wDTtvtynrI-yqw_ccnPGj_QDKMGus_/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could you please provide the documentation on the method you're using? Also, can you provide the code related to the `OAuth` process you're following?